# HTA Change Icon in title bar and taskbar

Tags: hta

I wanted to know if there was a simple way to change my HTA application's icon I have found answers but it always uses another program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use a custom icon for HTA, you'll need an `.ico` file. Then you can assign an icon to a file in `<HTA>` like this:

```
<HTA:application
    icon = "path_to_icofile"
>
```

By my experience, Windows7 doesn't have full support for all features for`HTA` object. Unfortenately `icon` is one of those partly non-supported features. The file with custom icon occasionally looses its icon and uses some random icon instead.

You can read more about HTAs at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536471%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @James_Parsons I haven't tested HTAs in Windows8, so I don't know. You can easily test it yourself, please let me know then. Anyway, it seems that when installing a new OS or IE version, something from functionality of HTAs is dropped every time.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has removed this functionality since IE10 was introduced.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/fa1a9128-c933-409b-9d6e-11770e631e52/htaapplication-tag-does-not-work-in-ie10?forum=iewebdevelopment

Comment: is there another way to do it

Comment: @James_Parsons Yes, you can split the HTA settings into a `.hta` file, while setting `NAVIGABLE=yes`, and have a script set the `window.location` to a standard HTML file. The HTA settings will be respected, you'll have the full HTA permissions, but you'll also be able to use the latest IE engine. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35307743/111794).

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10, change the syntax slightly

```
<HTA:application
    icon = 'path_to_icofile'
>
```