# HTA and 'x-ua-compatible' meta tag

Tags: vbscript, meta-tags, internet-explorer-11, hta

Added to post Jun-19-2014

Thanks Bond. Since you had IE9, I appreciate your test.  Hopefully if somebody out there has IE 10 they will test it, too.  It does not make any sense why under the IE 11 engine you can only run compatibility up to ie8.

---

I created this tiny, itty-bitty HTA in order to post it so hopefully I can find out what I am missing.

My system is a Win7 Pro 64bit with IE 11.

When I set the meta tag as:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=8">
```

the HTA runs peachy-keen.  No problems.  But when I change it to:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9">
```

it doesn't run so good.

Now ... I know that there was a big family blow-out between IE 11 and VBScript.  VBscript got booted out of the house for good.  IE 11 refuses to communicate with it anymore.  So I can understand why setting it to content="ie=edge" would not work.  But why doesn't it work when setting it to content="ie=9"?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=8">
<hta:application
applicationname="Hmmmmmm"
singleinstance="yes"
id="oHTA"
>
<title>Huh? What?</title>
<script language="VBScript">

Option Explicit
Dim objFSO,file

Sub Window_OnUnLoad
   Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set file=objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\temp\submit.txt",2,True)
   file.Write oHTA.document.getElementById("aa").value
   file.Close
   Set objFSO=Nothing
   Set file=Nothing
End Sub

Sub Window_OnLoad
   window.ResizeTo 240,130
End Sub

Function Form_OnSubmit()
   window.Close
   Form_OnSubmit=False
End Function

</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:30px;">
<form id="form" action="">
<input id="aa" type="text" size="10" value="test">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Running it as ie8 set in the meta tag works fine ... window pops up, gets resized, and writes to the file on submit ... glory-be!

Running it as ie9 set in the meta tag ... window pops up, resizing is ignored, and writing to the file is ignored ... as if all the VBScript is being ignored.

What information am I missing?

Comment: VBScript does work in IE11, you just need to be on an intranet or choose compatability.

Comment: @phd443322 How else you could execute an HTA?

Comment: phd- I know IE 11 does not run vbscript. I said that. I also know to run compatabilty, which is why I posted this problem. Running this simple thing (mshta.exe) with content=ie8 works fine but running as content=ie9 does not.  I am trying to find out why.

Comment: Just FYI, I have IE9 installed and it does work with content=ie9. I was hoping it wouldn't so that I could help troubleshoot. :)

Comment: @Cooper: "as IE=8 breaks the CSS, IE=11 or IE=Edge seems to break the VBS " ... Well IE 10 breaks the <HTA:APPLICATION tag in some points as for example the application icon not shown on the left of the application title bar... I see why MS abandoned IE with all the flaws it has. IE will be soon an abandon-ware... hope sooner... ah right sooner is already yesterday... The inconvenient is that for HTAs there is not a real alternative yet in Windows, a part maybe powershell and winforms, But those are It is too convulse and much more complex to handle. I rather use JavaScript in HTAs instead -->

Comment: <-- But even using JavaScript not all problems will go away only some are

Answer (score 8):

Looks like later versions of IE is not supporting HTA as mentioned in the other answers.
One solution to your problem is: Make your HTA file navigable (HTA attribute `navigable="yes"`) and do not specify any `x-ua-compatible` meta tags. In the HTA file navigate to another file which has the `x-ua-compatible` tag. The file you navigated will have the HTA priviliges:

HTA File:

```
<!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
   <HTA:APPLICATION 
    navigable="yes" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
    document.location = 'htacontent.htm';
  //-->
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

htacontent.htm

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
...
```

Comment: A minor issue: there won't be any way to access the HTA-specific properties from within `htacontent.htm`.

Comment: But since virtually all of the settings cannot be set via Javascript, I suppose it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Another problem here is that if you set `singleinstance="yes"` it will refocus the original HTML Application, but it will also open an IE window containing the file in the background.

Answer (score 3):

I've just faced the same problem.

The solution is to put `Window` in lower case ! It is especially astonishing as usually VBScript is not case sensitive !

So declare `Sub window_onLoad` instead of `Sub Window_onLoad`, and so on... Finally your script should work. *Tested on a Win7 Pro 64bit with IE 11, like yours.*

IE strikes back !

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm, *(for some extremely odd reason)*; both **CED** and **TRSyntax** are on to something!
- Thanks by the way guys! - I'd have never 'guessed' this *(and I thought I knew VBS quite well...)*

Just as a quick bit of background information: I was simply trying to make my HTA prettier - it was already fully functional (this includes the fact I had my onload written literally as `Window.OnLoad()` and I added `border-radius` to my CSS and found it didn't work. - Bit of research suggested that I needed to add extra 'compatibility' via the Meta declaration of `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge" />`

Immediately after doing this my entire HTA's VBS broke - I tried different 'Content Modes' and discovered `content="IE=8"` allowed the VBS to work again but 'back to square one' in that it was ignoring the CSS for `border-radius`.

This is when I finally arrived here - it would seem that adding the meta makes interpretation of the VBS stricter which is perhaps why my OnLoad function was now invalid... (although a strange note is the fact my original `Window.OnLoad()` is invalid but `window.OnLoad()` is valid...) Merely changing the **W** on "Window" and keeping the same **O** for "On" fixed the problem, I presumed the "OnLoad" would also need changing to "onLoad" but this isn't the case...

So to summarise (to stop me waffling on too much) I will share my working settings:

Top of the document: `<!DOCTYPE html>`
*I put this in for 'good practice' when making HTML5 based web pages, although it's not actually needed here with the meta declaration.*
Within the `<head>`: `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10" />`
*For some strange reason I get best overall results with IE=9 or IE=10. Any of the others seem to cause problems such as IE=8 breaks the CSS, IE=11 or IE=Edge seems to break the VBS*
Within the `<head><script>`: `Sub window_OnLoad()`
*Thanks to the kind folk on this page, I realised "Window" cannot contain any capitals, although after the dot; case no longer matters, eg: `window.ONLOAD()` is still valid & works but looks ugly...*

Within the `<head><style>`:

```
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

*I just added this because I'm starting to waffle, but it might be useful to someone - it's just the CSS rule that puts a border on Tables, Table Headers & Cells and then if all else is working nicely the border will have rounded corners* :D

Anyhow - many thanks to all - much respect to StackOverflow! - Maybe one day I'll sign up and make a real account :P

Answer (score 0):

Later versions than IE9 aren't made to be compatible with HTA. So if you put the `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9" />` tag, it won't support things for HTA like `<hta:application>`, VBScript or frames. I also have that problem and what I do is that I just try to work around the things that don't work in early versions of IE (for example see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982973/is-it-possible-to-run-some-html5-input-types-in-ie8/27090739#27090739)). You don't seem to use things that don't work in early versions of IE in the HTA that you posted. If you tell me exactly what you're using that doesn't work in IE7, I might be able to give you a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

as ced said before me, "The solution is to put Window in lower case", "So declare Sub window_onLoad instead of Sub Window_onLoad".

my issue came up when i use both js and vbs in a HTA. but after matching my case to my java "window.onload = function ()" sub everything works well together. vb itself is case-insensitive but this might be some mshta.exe specific behavior.