# HTA gives error in combination with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hta

I made a angularjs HTML SPA that works fine.In a specific situation I need the power of a HTA. As far as I know there are no restrictions in using a HTA in combination with angular or any other valid HTML. Nevertheless I get an error when using the line

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

in a HTA, even when it's the only script tag in the header.

The error message is: Script error, Code 0, URL http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js

I would expect that others have encountered this error before but I can't find anything on stackoverflow.Does anybody recognize this problem? Is there a solution or workaround?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-US" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <head>
        <HTA:APPLICATION
      APPLICATIONNAME="my app"
      SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div >   
            ...Do something
            </div> 
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Consider that HTAs are proprietary and only work with Internet Explorer and haven't changed much since IE9 then you might see the root of the problem. Also consider its default standard mode renders as IE7 Standard and quirks mode renders using IE5 (quirks mode).

Comment: Thanks for the considerations Lankymart. In relation to the second one, I also tried the X-UA-Compatible META tag

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `ng-app` and `ng-controller` on HTML element, but its handlers are not defined.  Also, as noted in comment, you must elevate implicit IE version to use sane JS engine with `X-UA-Compatible` meta.  Adding those two lines fixes described error:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en-US" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
  <HTA:APPLICATION
  APPLICATIONNAME="my app"
  SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script>angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('myCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){}])</script> 
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>   
  ...Do something
  </div> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Setting IE version 10 and higher via `X-UA-Compatible` meta gets `<HTA>` tag ignored, tested on IE 11.

Comment: @omegastripes A possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35307743/111794). I haven't tested it, but it should keep the `HTA` tag settings while allowing the use of recent Javascript , HTML and CSS.