# HTA icon not showing up using IE10

Tags: hta

I need to use something which is compatible with IE10 and not with IE9.

My HTA was made for IE9 and worked fine : visible icon and maximized windows.

By changing `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9"/>` to `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=10"/>`, there is no icon and the windows is not maximized.

Any idea please ?

**NOT working :**

```
<html>

<head> 
<title>test</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION ID = "1"
    APPLICATIONNAME="1"
    BORDER="thin"
    BORDERSTYLE="normal"
    ICON="icon.ico"
    MAXIMIZEBUTTON="yes"
    MINIMIZEBUTTON="yes"
    SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"
    SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
    SYSMENU="yes"
    WINDOWSTATE="maximize">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=10"/>
</head>
<!---->
<body style="overflow:hidden;">
No icon and not maximized, with ie=10
</body>
</html>
```

**Working :** but I need IE10 now.

```
<html>
<head> 
<title>Test</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION ID = "1"
    APPLICATIONNAME="1"
    BORDER="thin"
    BORDERSTYLE="normal"
    ICON="icon.ico"
    MAXIMIZEBUTTON="yes"
    MINIMIZEBUTTON="yes"
    SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"
    SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
    SYSMENU="yes"
    WINDOWSTATE="maximize">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9"/>
</head>
<!---->
<body style="overflow:hidden;">
Icon showing correctly with ie=9
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IE9 was the last version supporting HTA. In IE10 and IE11 modes HTA tag is automatically moved to the body section, and all the properties given in HTA tag are unsupported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What usually works for me, is to have an HTA with `NAVIGABLE` set to `yes`, and changing the `window.location` to an HTML file using standard HTML. This allows the use of the HTA properties on the one hand, and the use of `IE=edge` (or another targeted IE version) on the other:

**myHTA.hta**

```
<html>
<head> 
<title>test</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION ID = "1"
    APPLICATIONNAME="1"
    BORDER="thin"
    BORDERSTYLE="normal"
    ICON="icon.ico"
    MAXIMIZEBUTTON="yes"
    MINIMIZEBUTTON="yes"
    NAVIGABLE="yes"
    SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"
    SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
    SYSMENU="yes"
    WINDOWSTATE="maximize">

<script>
    window.location = 'htaContent.html';
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

**htaContent.html**

```
<html>
<head> 
<title>test</title>
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=10"/>
</head>
<body style="overflow:hidden;">
    Put your HTML content here
</body>
</html>
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35307743/111794).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your code works as I have a maximized window and an icon, but it opens a new IE windows instead of showing the content of the .html file into the HTA. How can I have everything in the same window ?

Comment: @Hugo7 You have to set `NAVIGABLE=yes` in your HTA. I've updated my answer.

Comment: There's a typo in myHTA.hta, the `window.location` statement. Should be `'` after `htaContent.html` instead of a `\``. Not allowed to edit only 1 character so writing a comment instead